# Bootstrap 4 Nav items - cursor is an I-beam

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4, beta 2 in an angular 5 project, but I'm including it statically from a  tag to avoid bundling issues.  When hovering over Nav bar items, the mouse turns into an I-beam.  What is overriding the default behavior on links in a nav item to suppress the default behavior of the cursor?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link">
```

etc.  Just a plain vanilla Bootstrap navbar.  Why am I not getting a pointer cursor?

Comment: Have you double checked your css for anything that might be setting `cursor: {something else}`?

Comment: Figured it out - you _have_ to put href="" on the <a> tag.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and, to close this question, I'm shamefully confirming that user3174133's comment below the question fixes the issue:

- simply add the HREF on the `<a class="nav-link">` anchor tag and you'll see the finger pointer (instead of the "I" cursor), like this:

  ```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-expand">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
             <a HREF="yourURL" class="nav-link">
  ```